# Can't find script engine JScript, or Command CScript

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cordova, windows-phone

I'm trying to develop an app for Windows Phone using Apache Cordova (PhoneGap). I've installed the Windows Phone SDK from Microsoft's web site (SDK 7.1 for Windows Vista+); the SDK comes with Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone. I'm also using Windows 7 Professional, 64bit.

I've imported the PhoneGap template perfectly, should be no issues here. When I try to emulate my app on the "Windows Phone Emulator", I get the following errors:

[image: Attempting to Run App in Emulator]

I've tried reinstalling Visual Basic/the SDK, PhoneGap countless time (plus tried different versions), I've tried everything posted previously on Stackoverflow and also from other web sites.

My JS files are being detected normally via Windows Explorer, so I don't think there is a wrong file association. I've also attempted to insert additional code, or modify code in the .csproj file and the BuildManifestProcessor.js; but no luck either.

Are there any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the definite solution, after trying many solutions; such as using regsvr32 attempting to fix JScript and VBScript association. Even if your associations are working perfectly, you can still receive the above error.

To solve this problem, run this tool (by Microsoft): http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_media_player_diagnostic/

It will solve your problem. I understand this is for Windows Media Player, but it will also fix any JS or VB.NET problems too.

It will also fix Windows Media Player problems too, such as "**server execution failed**"; which is caused due to JS/VB.NET too.

I am now able to begin development for Windows Phone; to be honest, I'm excited.

All the best.